# How do you reference a SharePoint group in a workflow?

Tags: workflow, groups

Look for a way to reference a SharePoint group in my workflow.  I want to set a variable equal to the group.  Not sure how to do that?

Comment: Reference it how? To get the name? To get the members? To determine which groups a user are part of? To email the members? To assign something to them? As a text variable?

Comment: I'm trying to get the Group's email address.

Comment: Is this in Designer or Visual Studio? Are you looking to send an email or just get the email address to use as a string elsewhere?

Comment: I wanted to get the email address and set it as a variable to send emails.

Comment: Is this in Designer or Visual Studio?

Comment: Designer.  I don't know how to use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

in my Visual Studio workflow I just reference either the group's  name as a string or the groups ID.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your workflow in SharePoint Designer (assuming 2013 as you didn't specify), add an email action and set the desired target (To/CC/BCC) to whichever group you'd like from the 'Select from existing users and groups' list on the left and hit add. It should email the group directly. No need to involve a variable in the equation.

If for some reason, you really wanted to, you could add a variable and then use a web service call to one of the REST services to get the user's email address as a string and then assign that to a variable, but that's needlessly complicating things.

A quick visual tutorial can be found [here](http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-tutorials/Creating-workflow-sends-email/144025/161215-4.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I had a security group from ad setup for permissions in SP, but couldn't find them in the list.  I set up a SharePoint group and now that shows up in the list and I can email the users of that group.

Comment: I've seen in another workflow that a variable was set for groupname@domain.com and then in the address they referenced the Variable and it would email the group members.  I tried that and for some reason it doesn't email the address of the variable.

Comment: SharePoint is finicky that way. It prefers to do everything through its user/group list and active directory tie-throughs. If you have to send emails to users/groups/email addresses outside of that, you have to use web services or custom code to communicate and have emails sent. It's arduous and best to just use the options provided out of the box.